# Unzip file is not working

Tags: node.js, express, zip, unzip, adm-zip

Im using the following code from

https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/wiki/ADM-ZIP-Introduction

Whant I need is to get a zip file from request(Im using **express** and I've request and response) and I need to extract(unzip) it to some path(in the example for my local drive) ,where should I put the req and what Im missing here to make it work

```
  fn: function (req, res) {
       var admZip = require('adm-zip');

        var zip = new admZip();

        zip.addLocalFile("C://TestFolder//TestZip");
```

in the request body im getting the zip file(im using postman and in the body I use the binary and select a zip file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try my snippet code :

For some information, My App structure like this below :

```
my path --> C:\xampp\htdocs\service

service
    |
    -- tmp\
    |
    -- app.js
    |
    -- index.html
```

### Client Side:

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>ZIP Upload:</h3>
<form action="/upload_zip" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select zip to upload:
    <input type="file" name="zipFile" id="zipFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload ZIP" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Server Side:

Don't forget using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` when you post it using postman or something like that...

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
var app = express();

var multer = require("multer");
var multer_dest = multer({dest: "./tmp"}).single('zipFile');

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log("Show index.html");
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/"+"index.html");
});

app.post("/upload_zip",multer_dest,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.file);  
    var zip = new AdmZip(req.file.path); 
    zip.extractAllTo("./tmp");
    result = {
        file:req.file,
        message:"File has been extracted"
    };
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, function (e) {
        if (e) throw e;
        console.log('successfully deleted '+req.file.path);
    });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
});

var server = app.listen(8081,function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log("Example App Listening at http://%s:%s",host,port);
})
```

### Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the problem by using `form-data` instead of `binary` and using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). You can get the input file by accessing `req.file` after which you can perform your unzip operation.

For example, you would add to your route:

```
var upload = require('multer')({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var admZip = require('adm-zip');


app.post('/upload-here', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
    var zip = new admZip(req.file.path);

    zip.extractAllTo("C://TestFolder//TestZip", true);
});
```

Comment: Go to the form data section, set key as 'file' (if you modify this, then modify in `upload.single('file')` too) and choose from the drop box to the right 'File'